# Does View.OnTouchListener run on other thread than the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ontouchlistener

If I have a class object `Square` (that is not the `MainActivity`, but `MainActivty` creates `Square` objects) that implements `View.OnTouchListener`, does the `onTouch()` method within `Square` run on the UI thread or another thread?

It seems like it is running on another thread, since I cannot update the UI from within the `onTouch()` method without calling `runOnUiThread()` on my `MainActivity` object.

**=== EDIT GOES BELOW ========================**

I logged `Thread.currentThread().toString()` as suggested by @pskink, and got the following result:

`onCreate() in MainActivity: Thread[main,5,main]
onTouch() in Square: Thread[main,5,main]`

So, it is clear now, the `onTouch()` method that I have running in `Square`, runs on the UI/main thread.

Thanks everyone for the help! :-)

Comment: `"It seems like it is running on another thread, since [...]"`, simply `Log.d` the value of `Thread.currentThread()` inside your `onTouch` method

Comment: that all depends on which thread called it. It can be called on any thread in general. But the system will call it on UI thread, if it is implemented in regular way to react on touches.

Comment: @VladMatvienko if you call `View#setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener l)` then `View.OnTouchListener` will always be called in the main UI thread

Comment: @pskink, not if you call it manually on another thread, or any other code calls it on another thread. That's what I told in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Does View.OnTouchListener run on other thread than the UI thread?

No. it is supposed to called in UI thread

Answer (score 0):

please use below code to know if current thread is UI/Main thread or not.

```
if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   // Current Thread is Main Thread.
}
or you can also use this

if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
   // Current Thread is Main Thread.
}
```

From my perspective it is running on UI thread if you still have a doubt you can put above code inside onTouchListener and check it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does View.OnTouchListener run on UI thread?

Yes. 100%. System will be calling all the methods on UI thread by default.

But you can perform operations on worker thread inside `onTouch()` method.

**Ps,

UI changes must be performed on `UI Thread`. Consider calling `runOnUiThread` while you need to update an UI from `worker thread`. You should consider use threading to avoid ANR (Application not responding). A good start is `AsyncTask`, that has it own method to do logic in a separate thread and update the UI on the `Main Thread`.**

Comment: there is no exception: `View.OnTouchListener` will always be called on the main UI thread

Comment: Yeah you're right. I watched that actually in my code. It actually run on `MainThread` no matter where you are setting `OnTouchListener`. But what about AIDL processes?? because documentation says "Calls made from the local process are executed in the same thread that is making the call. If this is your main UI thread, that thread continues to execute in the AIDL interface. If it is another thread, that is the one that executes your code in the service. " Check out this link - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: i dont really understand how you would call `View#setOnTouchListener` so that the listener to be called as an `AIDL` interface

Comment: I'm not talking about `onTouch()` itself. My context was to code inside `onTouch()`. You can do operation on worker thread inside `onTouch()`, while `onTouch` will always be called on `MainThread`.

Comment: for the question: `Does View.OnTouchListener run on UI thread?` your answer was: `Yes. Almost 100% Exception:-

If you are exposing interface via AIDL`